# How to get one class array list data in another class using NSUserDafaults

Tags: ios, swift

I am beginner in objective-c in my project i want to get one class arry-list data in another class using NSUserDefaults and i have done here some code for doing this  but it's not working please help me some one

### this is my main class and i am calling displayData method from sub class when ever we click button

```
- (IBAction)btnDisplayClicked:(id)sender{

    ModelManager *mgrObj=[ModelManager getInstance];
    [mgrObj displayData];//Calling here sub class method displayData

    NSMutableArray *myArr;
    myArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    myArr =[userDefaults objectForKey:@"array"];
    NSLog(@"array values are %@",myArr);
}
```

### This is my sub class:-

```
-(void)displayData
{
    [instance.database open];

    FMResultSet *rs = [instance.database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM studentInfo1"];

    rowData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    while ([rs next]) {

        for(int i=0; i<[rs columnCount]; i++) {

            [rowData addObject:[[rs resultDict] objectForKey:[[rs columnNameForIndex:i] lowercaseString]]];
             }
         }

     NSLog(@"%@",rowData);

     NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:rowData forKey:@"array"];

    [instance.database close];
}
```

Comment: add this line after add object in nsuser defaults `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` @Ramakrishna

Comment: but not working it trows excetions like NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object

Comment: a delegate or notification might be an easier solution if the data couldn't be written to user defaults.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:rowData forKey:@"array"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

It will work

Comment: yes i tried but it trows excetions like NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object